# Is there an option: only_summaries in Scapy?

Tags: python-3.x, wireshark, scapy, pcap, pyshark

I am processing a huge pcap file by Scapy, but it's slow.

When I am planning refactoring it by Pyshark, I found that there is an function named 'pyshark.FileCapture()' which offers a option: only_summaries.

That's what I want. So, is there any option or method in Scapy too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does't have. I got this answer on github by gpotter2 who one of the person in charge of scapy.

See https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1509

> If you want to perform the better, you can use with
>
> ```
> PcapReader(filename) as reader:
>     for pkt in reader:
>         [... actions on  the pkt ...] You can store specific informations on the packet that you want, or directly perform actions
> ```
>
> on the packet. But scapy does not have a only_summaries by itself:
> scapy would have to dissect the packet anyways, before returning only
> some few informations